# Updating from RxJS5 to RxJS6

Tags: angular, rxjs6

This code works on Rxjs5. How can I write this code with Rxjs6.

```
this.searchTerm$.distinctUntilChanged().combineLatest(
  this.selectedLg$.distinctUntilChanged(), (_term, _lg) => {
    return {
      term: _term,
      lg: _lg
    }
  }
)
  .switchMap(t => this.service.search(t.lg, t.term))
  .subscribe((results: any[]) => {
    this.list= results;
  });
```

Comment: You have to use pipe able Operators in RxJs6. https://medium.com/@swapnilkls29/rxjs-6-0-migration-37a6f3de0000 might be of help

Comment: Thanks,I think this will be work. Not testing yet. `this.searchTerm$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      combineLatest(this.selectedLg$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()), (_term, _lg) => {
        return {
          term: _term,
          lg: _lg
        }
      }),
      switchMap(t => this.service.search(t.lg, t.term))
    ).subscribe((results: any[]) => {
      this.list= results;
    });`

Comment: If you need a fast fix, you can also add the `rxjs-compat` package to your project, which allows you to use old syntax. Don't forget to also modify your imports when you switch to V6!

Comment: @Will Alexander Yes, I read about rxjs-compact but I want to use last syntax. Thanks.